# Check if current user is member of SharePoint group or Not

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, modern-pages

I have this method to check whether the current logged in user belongs to a certain group (IT Department) or no?
It returns true if the user is in the group. However I am member of that group but I get a false. What could possibly be problematic ?

```
function isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName) {
var isUserInGroup = false;
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    method: "GET",
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/groups",
    success: function (data) {
        data.d.results.forEach( function (value) {
            if (value.Title == groupName) {               
                 isUserInGroup = true;
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response.status);
    },
});    
return isUserInGroup;
}

var isAdmin = isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("IT Department");
 console.log('isadmin?' + isAdmin)
```

Comment: On which environment you are running this code? Is it SharePoint online or on Premise?
If SharePoint online then on modern Page or classic page?

Comment: Sharepoint Online. Modern

Comment: are you able to get the URL in your ajax call?

Comment: @user3660293: Do you want to use this code in SPFx web part or you would like to use it in classic experience page?

Comment: i have it in Modern Script Editor web part

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to access the `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` ?

As per [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/spPageContextInfo-is-undefined/m-p/153892) post `_spPageContextInfo` does not work in the Modern site of SharePoint Online.

You can use the approach mentioned in the mentioned link to get the site URL.

Comment: how do I know if I am able to access that page?

Comment: Write that in console of the browser and check if you are getting the URL or not ?

Comment: it works. It give me alot of data

Answer (score 0):

can you please change the actual rest query to get the value of all the groups current user is associated to as below in bold text

```
 function isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName) {
    var isUserInGroup = false;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        method: "GET",
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups",
        success: function (data) {

success: function (data) { 
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.Groups.results.length; i++) 
     { 
   console.log(data.d.Groups.results[i].Title); 
    if (data.d.Groups.results[i].Title == groupName) {               
                     isUserInGroup = true;
                }
       }

        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.status);
        },
    });    
    return isUserInGroup;
    }
```

Mind the change in:

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups",
```

Comment: i get :  TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: instead of data.d.results use data.d.Groups.results

Comment: let me know if you still receive the error or any other error

Comment: i get RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: so you use different code to make it work. the above answer provided by dhuvil is just whether you can access _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl is in page or not. there is no solution but you mention as Answer. may i know the reason

Comment: no its not the solution. I just mentioned that putting that url in the console works

Comment: oh ok. if my suggestion works for you marked as Answer. else let me know if you have issue

Comment: it helped the undefined forEach indeed. but now im facing RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, that perhaps holds me back from determining if the user belongs to a group

Comment: I ran the same code in my machine, it did not give this error for me. may be you are part of Multiple groups

Comment: how did you know that it worked? did you add something in the success code block?

Comment: I dont know why it is not working.  i added console.log(isUserInGroup) and is not executed at all, because value.Title == groupName is not true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98579/discussion-between-user3660293-and-vinit-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online - check if a User is in a group with jSOM for your reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-online-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-group-with-jsom